# Use iCloud To Restore Non-Renewing Subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, icloud, subscription

Apple's IAP Guide states that when using non-renewing subscriptions, you should offer a method to restore the subscription on all devices, using iCloud or your own server.  My question is simply this (I don't have a server):

How in the world can you use iCloud to store that the user has a subscription and to restore it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm just looking into this, and for what I understand you must save your relevant data (that is, subscription expiry, typically) in a file that will be saved when a iCloud backup is performed.

This way, the file will be sync in all devices, and your users will enjoy the subscription paid in one device, among all of them.

Customers should be warned they have to use iCloud or they won't have it available everywhere, of course.

Hope this helps,

jaime